# maven-deploy-plugin not executing its execution

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I need to deploy custom jar's from my project itself I overrides maven-deploy-plugin with two more execution with its default execution. below are my pom.xml with distributionManagement and maven-deploy-plugin which I use for my deployment.

```
<groupId>mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>temp</id>
        <name>Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8000/nexus/content/repositories/temp/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        some dependency
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        some dependency
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        some dependency
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>myjar-one</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <repositoryId>temp</repositoryId>
                        <url>http://localhost:8000/nexus/content/repositories/temp/</url>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <artifactId>myjar-one</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <sources>${project.build.directory}/build/lib/myjar-one.jar</sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>


                <execution>
                    <id>myjar-two</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <repositoryId>temp</repositoryId>
                        <url>http://localhost:8000/nexus/content/repositories/temp/</url>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <artifactId>myjar-two</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <sources>${project.build.directory}/build/lib/myjar-two.jar</sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>
```

Comment: And how are you executing this pom file? What mvn command you use to deploy the jar?

Comment: $ mvn clean deploy, its a multi module project this will execute as a last module in reactor.

Comment: Why are you trying to deploy separate files via deploy plugin? Does not make sense. Just use `mvn clean deploy`. If those libs should be used better upload them to a repository manager (which you seemed to be using) and that's it.

Comment: Do `myjar-one.jar` and `myjar-two.jar` change per `${project.version}` or are they always the same ?

Comment: @ khmarbaise I did not get you exactly, but in final module I assembled all jar previously buid and make a single jar by un-zip  and zip, that zip file would me my deploy-able jar

Comment: @mediahype they would be change as per there previous module changes, and yes they will change as per ${project.version}

Comment: Thanks for comment guys I fixed this issue, please look in answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I figure out the issue, there are following thing I need to fix.

1. Need to add goal.
2. Need to use file tag instead of source tag.
   So final maven-deploy-plugin looks like.

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>default-deploy</id>
               <phase>none</phase>
           </execution>

           <execution>
               <id>myjar-one</id>
               <phase>deploy</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>deploy-file</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <repositoryId>temp</repositoryId>
                   <url>http://localhost:8000/nexus/content/repositories/temp/</url>
                   <packaging>jar</packaging>
                   <artifactId>myjar-one</artifactId>
                   <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                   <version>${project.version}</version>
                   <file>${project.build.directory}/build/lib/myjar-one.jar</file>
               </configuration>
           </execution>


           <execution>
               <id>myjar-two</id>
               <phase>deploy</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>deploy-file</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <repositoryId>temp</repositoryId>
                   <url>http://localhost:8000/nexus/content/repositories/temp/</url>
                   <packaging>jar</packaging>
                   <artifactId>myjar-two</artifactId>
                   <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                   <version>${project.version}</version>
                   <file>${project.build.directory}/build/lib/myjar-two.jar</file>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

   after fixing this issue, my both custom jar's are deployed at my maven repository. Thanks for help

Comment: I want to add, for people stumbling upon this later in time. The catch here is that you defined
'<execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
'
Without this, the mojo will fail telling you, you need to define file, url, etc.